# else if statement not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I removed the variable names and just put the values in for simplicities sake.

Can't work out why this doesn't work properly, the `else` statement works fine, the `if` statement works fine but the `else if` part doesn't.

```
 if (scrollTop > 200) {

    $('.vote-next-hover').css({

        position: 'fixed',
        top: '50px',
        width: statuscontain,

    });

 } 

 else if (scrollTop > 5500) {

     $('.vote-next-hover').css({

        position: 'absolute',
        top: '',
        width: '',

     });

 } 

else {

  $('.vote-next-hover').css({

        position: 'relative',
        top: '',
        width: '',
    });

}
```

Scroll 200px, fires the if statement, scroll back to less than 200 and it fires the else statement, but at no point does it fire the else if statement.

I thought it would sort of be - Condition 1 met, fires - Condition 2 met, fires - Condition 3 met, fires?

Comment: don't you need `top: '0px'` or something?

Comment: also, did you try to debug it step by step?

Comment: no, those are to clear the declarations.

Comment: `else` means that the previous condition is not met. If `scrollTop > 5500` chances are it is also ` > 200`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should swap the `if` and `else if` clauses. See, if `scrollTop` value is greater than `5500`, it's definitely greater than `200` - therefore it will pass the very first check quite well, making the second one meaningless.

So `if (scrollTop > 5500)` should go first in your code, followed by `else if (scrollTop > 200)` check.

---

I wonder did you know that the same branching logic could be written with... `switch`?

```
var hoverStyle = { position: 'relative', top: '', width: '' };
switch (true) {
  case scrollTop > 5500:
    hoverStyle.position = 'absolute';
    break;
  case scrollTop > 200:
    hoverStyle = { position: 'fixed', top: '50px', width: statuscontain };
}
$('.vote-next-hover').css(hoverStyle);
```

Some people even consider it more readable than `if-elseif-else`. But of course the same restrictions apply there - the less common cases should go first (or should be re-checked later).

As a sidenote, I really think there's no point duplicating `$('.vote-next-hover').css()` call within the branches. It's enough to separate only different parts of code - in this case, setting up the `.css()` param.

Comment: Or you could test for `(scrollTop > 200 && scrollTop <= 5500)` for your first step

Comment: ^ Yes, this, urgh I can't believe I didn't think of this before asking the question, thanks anyway. Wish I would award the correct answer to blair too.

Answer (score 1):

The if/else if/else block should only run one of the three choices. For example:

```
var test = 4;
if (test === 4) { //true
    test = 3;
} else if(test === 3) {//does not do, already did one
    test = 0
} else {
    test = “something”
}
```

So you need three if blocks, not if/else if/else.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have scrolled to 6000, 6000 is greater than 200, so the first condition is met. Then because you have an `else if` it doesn't test the second condition.

You have two options:

Add the scrollTop > 5500 check to inside the > 200 check, or replace the order of the `if, else if` to put the > 5500 check first, then then > 200 check.

```
if (scrollTop > 200) {
    if (scrollTop > 5500) {
        $('.vote - next - hover ').css({
            position: 'absolute ',
            top: '',
            width: '',
        });
    } else {
        $('.vote - next - hover ').css({
            position: 'fixed ',
            top: '50px ',
            width: statuscontain,
        });
    }
} else {
    $('.vote - next - hover ').css({
        position: 'relative ',
        top: '',
        width: '',
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Scroll 200px, fires the if statement, scroll back to less than 200 and
>   it fires the else statement, but at no point does it fire the else if
>   statement."

This is a logic error. Since any number higher than 5500 is also higher than 200, and when you use **else if** you're saying that the first criteria was not true.

You should change your code to:

```
if (scrollTop > 5500) {
    $('.vote-next-hover').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '',
        width: '',
    });    
}
else if (scrollTop > 200) {                      
    $('.vote-next-hover').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '50px',
        width: statuscontain,
    });

}
else {
    $('.vote-next-hover').css({

        position: 'relative',
        top: '',
        width: '',
    });    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This logic error

```
$('#crud_interval').bind("change", function() {

if( $('#crud_interval').val() ==='Daily' ) { //not running
    $('#crud_weekly_day').hide();
    $('#crud_monthly_date').hide();
} else if( $('#crud_interval').val() ==='Weekly' ) { //not running
    $('#crud_weekly_day').show();
    $('#crud_monthly_date').hide();
} else {
    $('#crud_weekly_day').hide();
    $('#crud_monthly_date').show();
}
```

});